# Android: how to protect the inner class from low API level

Tags: android, compatibility

Protect method invoking is easy for android, just put Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= xx is ok, meanwhile we can add "@SuppressLint("NewApi")" to prevent lint checking this.

But what about the inner class extending a class or implementing an interface for the high API level? Such as the AutoFocusMoveCallback is only available on API 16 and higher

```
    private class OnAutoFocusMoveCallback implements AutoFocusMoveCallback {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocusMoving(boolean start, Camera camera) {
        // TODO

    }

}
```

How to solve this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue.

Declaring such an inner class that related to classes/interfaces in the high API is ok.

Just make sure protecting the instantiating/using such classes with  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= xx, as below:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        mAutoFocusMoveCallback = new OnAutoFocusMoveCallback();
    }
```